# Excel autofill with where you get two results per row

Tags: excel

I have the following Spreadsheet

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Test A1 | `=A1` |
| Test A2 | `=A1` |
| Test A3 | `=A2` |
| Test A4 | `=A2` |
| Test A5 | `=A3` |
| Test A6 | `=A3` |
| Test A7 |  |
| Test A8 |  |
| Test A9 |  |
| Test A10 |  |

When I autofill column B, I would expect to show `=A4` (or the contents of `A4`) but instead it gives me `=A7` (the content of `A7`)

How can I bring Excel to fill it like

```
=A4
=A4
=A5
=A5
```

etc...
?

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),INDEX([A],ROW()/2),INDEX([A],(ROW()-1)/2))`

(or based on Harun24hr solution: `=INDEX([A],ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))`

You won't be able to autofill that for a formula (meaning that the row increases).

Use this formula within a table (insert > table) and it will expand itself to the whole column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: We can merge your and my solution to: `=INDEX([A],ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0))` or `=INDEX([A],ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0))` - depending on where the list starts :-) - presumably faster as avoiding Indirect.

Comment: Yes, index is better than indirect.